# Не срабатывает кнопка Отмена у окна Alert

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться с простой задачей. Задаю цикл и хочу чтобы при вводе числа большего 100 диалоговое окно закрывалось, а также при нажатии кнопки отмена i == null. Но этого не происходит. подскажите почему. вот код

```js
let i=1;
for (let n=1; n>=1; n++) {
    i = +prompt("Введите число большее 100");
    if ((i>100) || (i == null)) break;
}
```

Comment: У меня все работает

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно посмотреть внимательно на эту строку

```
i = +prompt("Введите число большее 100");
```

`prompt` при клике на отмену возвращает `Null`, НО вы приводите значение из `prompt` к числу `+prompt`

Если так сделать `Number(null)` будет 0

Значит тут нужно поменять условие на это `(i == 0)`

========

Если так сделать, то кнопка отмена будет работать. НО теперь будет пропускать 0, поэтому лучше значение из `prompt`  приводить к числу в момент сравнения